# Absolute value with axi interface

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an interferometer wave and want to rectify it.
The code is not performing absolute value correctly.

What is the problem with this code?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module abs(
  input clk,
  output  [15:0] m_axis_tdata,
  input m_axis_tready,
  output m_axis_tvalid,
            
  input[15:0] s_axis_tdata,
  output s_axis_tready,
  input s_axis_tvalid 
  );

  always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(m_axis_tready && s_axis_tvalid) begin 
      assign  m_axis_tdata = (s_axis_tdata< 0) ? -s_axis_tdata :s_axis_tdata;
    end 
  end 
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The original post code does not compile.

The following changes are made so that it compiles, behaves as an absolute value converter, is easier to understand as a SO answer, and provides a reference to the use of Verilog's operators WRT signed/unsigned numbers.

- Cleanup, remove dead code, align, minimize for clarity.
- Change code so that it compiles:
  Remove `assign` statement in procedural block.
  Change variable driven by procedural block to kind `reg`.
- Change assignment operator from blocking ( `=` ) to non-blocking ( `<=` ) to model sequential logic (registers).
- Change code to handle signed numbers by changing everything associated with the operator ( `<` ) to be signed.   The OP  omitted type's/kind's for the variables; Verilog defaults to unsigned `wire`.   Checking less than 0, will not behave as expected on unsigned variables.

See [SystemVerilog specification](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) Section **11.6.1 Rules for expression bit lengths**. Specifically context determined operators for more on how to use an operator on signed arguments.

This code compiles and behaves as an absolute value converter with registered output.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module abs(
  // inputs
  input      clk,
  input      m_axis_tready,
  input      s_axis_tvalid,
  input      signed [15:0] s_axis_tdata,
  // output
  output reg signed [15:0] m_axis_tdata
  );
  
  always@( posedge clk ) 
    if( m_axis_tready && s_axis_tvalid )  
      m_axis_tdata <= ( s_axis_tdata < 32'sb0 ) ? -s_axis_tdata : s_axis_tdata;

endmodule
```